# Automatically parallelize a .net application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically parallelize a .Net application in order to use multi core CPU.

I know if it's possible to do it with some coding, but, is there a tools or a "runtime?" that is able to run an application in parallel (multi threading) without do manually ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What operations do you want to parallelize? And for what purpose?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. On a multi-tasking operating system like windows you can start your application multiple times and those instances will run "parallel". Or do you want a tool that analyzes your whole code base and rewrites your code for parallelization? don't think this is possible in finite time.

Comment: I know async methods let you trivialize some parralelizations but you cant just flip a switch and tell the compiler to cut up your work for all the computing cores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there is no way to parallelize a .net application. The programmer must build for multi-threaded/parallel from the ground up, and certain application areas will not be suited to parallelization.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was just my question.